What are the specs that decide how a Screen Reader should behave?
I'm implementing a web application with high accessibility requirements. In come cases, the screen reader (VO) behaves in unexpected ways (for example, skips some elements).
To find out whether the bug is inside the screen reader, or my application code, or the browser, or somewhere else, I need to first know what the expected behavior is.
Given some HTML with some aria- attributes, what are all the specs that decide how exactly a screen reader should interact with it?
Is it even fully specified, and how much is left up to the implementor of the screen reader?

The answers given are good, but it's worth noting that screen readers are like any other user agent, in that they differ from each other in subtle and not-so-subtle ways. Just like you ideally test your sites in multiple browsers, it's important to test across multiple different screen readers in multiple form factors. Like any other technology, they have bugs and quirks and different behaviour above and beyond the specs. I highly recommend you plan to usability test your finished application with actual users of various kinds of accessible tech (inc. various screen readers, Braille displays).

Screen reader behavior is determined by several key factors:

WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines): Standards ensuring web content is accessible, guiding how screen readers interpret and present information.

WAI-ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications): Attributes added to HTML to provide screen readers with additional information, essential for dynamic content.

Operating System Accessibility APIs: OS-specific APIs (like Microsoft UI Automation) that screen readers use to access and describe UI elements.

User Preferences: Users can customize screen reader settings, such as speech rate, verbosity, and how specific elements are announced.

Speech Synthesis Engine: The quality and clarity of the text-to-speech engine that converts text into spoken words.

HTML Semantics and DOM: Proper use of HTML elements (like headings, labels) ensures effective content navigation by screen readers.

Screen Reader Features: Specific functionalities like reading modes, virtual cursors, and specialized commands for interacting with content.

Internationalization: Adaptation to different languages and regional settings for accurate pronunciation and support for various writing systems.


It looks complicated but it is seamless. Start mainly with ARIA and WCAG guidelines. Then move on to others

Short answer: All major screenreaders (VoiceOver, JAWS and NVDA) are quite stable and generally support HTML specs, so I suggest you first look for the bug in your code.
If you believe your code is correct, you could take a gander at the following ressources.

PowerMapper.com: HTML elements, screen reader compatability (2023)
W3C.org: HTML Accessibility API Mappings 1.0 (2024)

Long answer: Screenreaders take their cues from the Accessibility Tree, which is calculated from the DOM, which in turn is computed from the source code.
Screenreaders only relay what is presented to them. They do not make independent decisions and so far, there is no AI in any of them.
So when nothing is announced in a screenreader, it's because the Accessibility Tree has no relevant information to pass on, which is because the API did not pick up anything of interest from the DOM, which in turn points back at the source code.

MDN Web Docs: Accessibility Tree
Chrome for Developers: Full Accessibility Tree in Chrome DevTools

You mention using ARIA: Stay away from ARIA unless you know exactly what it does to your markup. Websites that use ARIA have way more accessibility issues than average.

The WebAIM Million 2024 report

